# core data - magical record migration changing attribute type

Tags: ios, core-data, migration, magicalrecord

I am using the magicalrecord framework instead pure core data and I have changed one attribute's type. My application is already on the appStore so I will need to use Migration to ensure users' data don't disappear.

I have searched like a looot and unfortunately haven't find a solution to use the "manual migration" (is what I figured I need to use) with magical record.

Can you please point me to the right direction?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice would be to use as much as possible the lightweight migration. Even when you think that you can't.

Maybe you could add a new attribute instead of editing one, and if you need it, create a one time migration task at the start of your app to transfer from the previous attribute to the new one (and making the type transition that you want). 
You will have a "dead" attribute for a while that you can remove when some time as past. That's the method I used for the past two years.

Migration are a bitch, always use the simplest solution.

Comment: Is that really the solution? Not for me perhaps. I don't need stacking new attributes every time I realize there's a change needed. Plus I want to learn something new

Comment: In that case you can create migration file : http://www.objc.io/issue-4/core-data-migration.html

Comment: I ended up with your advice and avoiding any advanced model changes. Thank you